# Mac OS X Development - WebView

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, webview

I have been battling this now for about a week. I am able to embed an `html` file in a WebView. How would I be able to make a button launch the WebView ?

Comment: you mean how to make a button set the URL of the Web View?

Comment: Just a note, if you are doing this on OSX (as your tags suggest) then the class is called WebView, not UIWebView. Please either fix the tags or the question/title.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup an IBAction for your button then do something like this:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"pathToFile"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"pathToFile"]];
```